# Help with Admin forms validation error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am quite new to Django, I'm having few problems with validation
forms in Admin module, more specifically with raising exceptions in the
ModelForm. I can validate and manipulate data in clean methods but
cannot seem to raise any errors. Whenever I include any raise
statement I get this error "'NoneType' object has no attribute
'ValidationError'". When I remove the raise part everything works
fine.

Then if I reimport django.forms (inside clean method) with a different alias (e.g. from django import forms as blahbalh) then I'm able to raise messages using blahblah.ValidateException.

Any tips or suggestions on doing such a thing properly ?

Here's an example of what I'm doing in Admin.py:

#### admin.py

from django import forms
from proj.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

class FontAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:

    model = Font

def clean_name(self):

    return self.cleaned_data["name"].upper()

def clean_description(self):

    desc = self.cleaned_data['description']
    if desc and if len(desc) < 10:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Description is too short.')
    return desc
```

class FontAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
form = FontAdminForm
list_display = ['name', 'description']
```

admin.site.register(Font, FontAdmin)

--
Thanks,
A

Comment: Is there some module variable named forms?

Comment: I meant a variable named forms in your admin.py that the interpreter might be seeing, rather than resolving the module forms itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem might be in the * import.

```
from proj.models import *
```

if proj.models contains any variable named forms (including some module import like "from django import forms), it could trounce your initial import of:

```
from django import forms
```

I would explicitly import from proj.models, e.g.

```
from proj.models import Font
```

If that doesn't work, see if there are any other variables name "forms" that could be messing with your scope.

You can use introspection to see what "forms" is.  Inside your clean_description method:

```
print forms.__package__
```

My guess is it is not going to be "django" (or will return an error, indicating that it is definitely not django.forms).

Comment: yes you are correct, it wasn't using the django.forms at all therefore the app was breaking, it's fixed now. SO THANKS for explaining.